# Unable to boot Mac OS and disk utility unable to repair disk after bootcamp delete windows partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, data-recovery

I’am not so sure whether it is related to bootcamp. after deleting the windows partition by bootcamp，the second day the computer can not boot and there is just question mark folder on the screen. when i follow the instructions on https://support.apple.com/zh-cn/HT204904 to enter the recovery mode and there is no startup disk can be found.

my mac version is MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).
Here is some information may help.

output of `diskutil list /dev/disk0` :

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         372.0 GB   disk0s2
```

output of `gpt -v -r show /dev/disk0`:

```
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=500277790720; sectorsize=512; blocks=977105060
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  726562776      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  726972416  250132611         
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

output of `fdisk /dev/disk0`:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60821/255/63 [977105060 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  977105059] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

output of `diskuti apfs list`:

```
|
+-- Container ERROR -69808
|   ======================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk1
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      ERROR -69620
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   ERROR -69620
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       ERROR -69620
|   |
|   +-< Physical Store disk0s2 F31C2BCB-9CEA-4449-9CAD-4893BBF532A5
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
|   |   Size:                       372000141312 B (372.0 GB)
|   |
|   +-> No Volumes
```

output of `diskutil info /dev/disk0`:

```
   Device Identifier:         disk0
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD SM0512G

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 500.3 GB (500277790720 Bytes) (exactly 977105060 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      No
```

output of `fsck_apfs -y  /dev/disk0s2`

```
warning: nx_block_count is 122086923, while device block count is 90820347
error: object (oid 0x1): o_cksum (0x27828005f8de019d) is invalid for object
** Checking the container superblock.
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 113
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 111
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 109
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 107
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 105
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 103
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 101
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 99
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 97
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 95
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 93
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 91
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 89
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 87
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 85
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 83
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 81
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 79
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 77
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 75
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 73
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 71
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 69
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 67
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 65
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 63
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 61
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 59
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 57
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 55
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 53
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 51
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 49
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 47
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 45
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 43
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 41
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 39
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 37
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 35
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 33
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 31
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 29
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 27
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 25
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 23
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 21
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 19
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 17
warning: checkpoint<->superblock disagree for xp 15
Too many warnings of this type generated; suppressing subsequent ones.
error: no valid checkpoint
   Most recent checkpoint is invalid.
** The volume /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely.
```

the output of disk utility：
[image: img1]

[image]

while when i enter `command+option+r` the disk utility shows the same diagnosis as above,
when i enter `command+r` the disk utility shows the disk is good.

Can anyone help to fix this problem or give any suggestions？ many thanks.
The data in the disk is really important to me.

Comment: The value of `726562776` in the GPT might be wrong. My guess would be to change the value to `976695384`. I would wait and see if someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, are these command below right to change the value to 976695384:



```gpt remove -i 2 disk0```



```gpt add -b 409640 -s 976695384 -i 2 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of 726562776 in the GPT might be wrong. My guess would be to change the value to 976695384. I would wait and see if someone else has a better idea.

The command to do this are given below. Here, I assume you have booted to a newer version of macOS Recovery.

```
gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0 
gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 976695384 -t apfs disk0
```

The older versions of macOS Recovery would require the longer commands given below.

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0 
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 976695384 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
```

### Why 976695384?

- **Reason 1:** The error message from your question, which is repeated below.

  ```
  warning: nx_block_count is 122086923, while device block count is 90820347
  ```

  Since the device block size is 4096 bytes and the sector size is 512 bytes, the conversion requires multiplying by 8, as shown below.

  ```
  122086923 blocks * 8 sectors per block = 976695384 sectors
  ```
- **Reason 2:** This is the largest sector size that will hold complete blocks. If you take 976695387 sectors and convert to whole blocks by dividing by 8 and discarding the remainder of 3, you get the following.

  ```
  976695387 sectors / 8 blocks per sector = 122086923 blocks
  ```

  Next, convert back to sectors, as shown below.

  ```
  122086923 blocks * 8 sectors per block = 976695384 sectors
  ```

  > This can be computed in your head. Basically, you divide the last three digits of 976695387 by 8 to get the remainder. In other words, `387 / 8 = 48` with remainder of 3. Next, subtract the remainder from 976695387 to get the result. In other words, `976695387 - 3 = 976695384`. *Why the last three digits?* Well, 976695387 can be written as `976695 * 1000 + 387`. Since 1000 is always evenly divisible by 8, you only need the last three digits to get the remainder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  It really helps. But can you tell me why the value is 976695384 while not 976695387?

Comment: I updated by answer.

Comment: I just wanted to say I had the same issue after deleting my Bootcamp volume and this worked!

Comment: David Anderson, I’m amazed of your explenation, I have the same issue but just after run the second command it says no space available on device. ```
[-bash-3.2# gpt remove -i 2 disk0
disk0s2 removed
[-bash-3.2# gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 976695384 -t apfs disk0
gpt add: /dev/disk0: error: no space available on device ```
do you have any advice how to handle it as it seems that yours steps helped out more people ;)